# Fixed size div and content, inside responsive div/container

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

I need to fit  a fixed size div and its content inside another div, but the outer div can be any size:  example:

Note: Boostrap is used on the site.  the inners div can contain any html element eg img, div tags and etc.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 outerdiv">
  <div class="innerdiv">
    <div style="width: 500px; height: 750px; position:relative;">
      <div style="left: 37px; top: 22px; width: 613.4px; height: 347.4px; text-align: center;position: absolute;">
        Some text
      </div>
      <div style="left:57px; top: 302px; width: 613.4px; height: 347.4px; position: absolute;">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/613x347" style="width: 613.4px; height: 347.4px;" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the solution i thought was to use, css3 `transform`  and `scale`. But this does not seem to work always, since  the content of inner div move out place, its needs keep the aspect ratio.

UPDATE: Fiddle  found here https://jsfiddle.net/TheDeveloper/1g585peo/9/

Comment: not sure what you are trying to accomplish from your question...what should happen when the outer div is smaller than the fixed inner div? what should happen when the outer div is larger?

Comment: @ryantdecker,   thanks for the comment,  if `outerdiv` is smaller,  i expect all the content in `innerdiv`  to scale  down and fit.  Same if  the `outerdiv` is large then i expect `innerdiv`  to scale up with content.

Comment: it might be easier to show a couple of images of what you are going for - you have bootstrap's 'col-sm-4' which is never going to be 500px wide but you're setting the width of the contents to 500px...so that's going to always overflow or get clipped, then your setting the child divs to 613.4px ...which is likewise going to overflow your 500px...so basically I can tell why its breaking, but I can't tell what you were trying for

Comment: @ryantdecker  , i have added a fiddle,  basically the red( top one)  shows what currently is happening and the green is what i want. `col-sm-4`  will change depending on screen, so i expect the inner div to follow.

Comment: if you want the things inside a div to resize when the div does, you can't use `px` to define them, you have to use something relative, like %....if your parent div is 500px, and you want the child to be 614px, you want to make the child `width:122.8%;` so that when the parent is resized, the child stays sized proportionately.

Comment: @ryantdecker thanks for comments :) ,  but in this scenario i have to use  `px`  so  `%`  is not possible

Comment: well, I'm happy to think on it some more, but the fiddle doesn't really help me with what you're trying to accomplish -- it seems contradictory to say you want it 'fixed' and 'it should scale'

Comment: @ryantdecker   hence why i tried using  css3 `transform:scale(0.60);`    buts its not perfect